# update other fields onchange in mobx react form

Tags: reactjs, mobx-react

I'm using the [nestedField demo example](https://foxhound87.github.io/mobx-react-form-demo/demo.html) of [Mobx-react-form](https://github.com/foxhound87/mobx-react-form) with a little alteration to the field list the rest of the code is as is. I want to be able to run a function every time any field get updated / changed and update the dependent fields of the form. therefore, the function needs access to all the fields in the form in order to recalculate / update other fields.

what I want to achieve is a calculator like functionality where items are added to a list (in a form) and as soon as the quantity or the price of an item is updated, the subtotal of the list and the grand total of the form gets recalculated. The form has multiple lists of items.

How can I do that?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The owner of the project responded, and help resolve the issue. for any one looking for the same here is the link - https://github.com/foxhound87/mobx-react-form/issues/307

The solution is to use a computed function which acts as a prop and gets updated every time anything changes in the state.

```
@computed get total() {
    let total = 0;

    form.$('fieldsArray')
      .map(field => (total = total + parseFloat(field.value)));

    return total;
}
```

the sub total can also be calculated in the same manner. to get the parent of the field use - `field.container()`